# Which one is the correct answer : "What do you do on Saturdays?" or "What time do you take your dog for a walk on Saturday?"

Tags: grammar, differences, time

Which of these questions is correct for "I take the dog for a walk every Saturday afternoon." :

a) What time do you take your dog for a walk on Saturday?
b) What do you do on Saturdays

thank you

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: It was...and I failed

Comment: I would have failed too - because neither of the two options seems "correct" to me Well, maybe in the context of a police interrogation, I would have picked (a) as a possible follow-up (with some reservations). And BTW, these are questions, not answers.

Comment: Neither of these is an answer; they are both questions.

Comment: If you mean: to which of these questions ("_What time do you..._" or "_What do you do..._") is the answer ("_I take the dog..._") more suitable, then please [edit] your question to reflect that. If that _is_ what you mean: both _could_ be a question to which "_I take the dog..._" is the answer, but neither are ideal matches.

Comment: Ah, so it's the other way around. But I still wouldn't know the "correct" answer here.

Comment: It seems that only in homework tasks do answers precede questions. In real-life situations, answers are usually fragments. You would soon lose conversation partners if you answered every question with a full sentence or repeated words from the question unnecessarily.

Comment: While both questions could result in the statement given as an answer, neither question-and-answer pair is completely idiomatic or literal. Without further information about what's required, the answer could be both, neither, or just one or the other. (In the first question, *time* does not mean *afternoon*, it means what the clock reads. Also, it uses a singular *Saturday* but the statement is about multiple Saturdays. In the second question, *afternoon* is information not asked for. So it leaves the answer possibly providing too much information or not providing enough.)

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct because they have Present Simple Tense, which is used for permanent or repeated actions, like habits or routines.
The permanent character of the action /walking the dog/  is marked by 'on Saturday'.